# rerun Javascript when dom updates from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying for a while to solve this problem I'm currently having, to no use untill now.

I have a main html file with a menu that loads content to a div trough ajax. The problem is that the loaded content (witch has a 'next' button to go to the...next dynamic loaded page) doesn't work, so I had to add a recall to the function I'm running on the parent page. Obviously this didn't went so well, because after clicking trough some of the links, I end up crashing the browser with more than 3000 request to the same function...

How can I make it so the function re-runs, or listens to DOM changes? And .on isn't working.

Script on the main file:

```
var din = function () {
    $('.dinMenu').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#dinContent').html('loading...');
        var $this = $(this);
        var module = $this.data("module");
        var folder = 'modules/module_' + module + '/';
        var href = $this.data("href");
        var url = folder + href;
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#dinContent').html(data);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#dinContent').html("Error!! File is not loaded");
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
     din();
    });
```

The HTML:

```
 ...
 <li class="dinMenu"><a href="#" data-href="child.html" data-module="1">link</a></li>
 ...
 <section class="panel content" id="dinContent" >
   <!-- start panel specific content -->
 ...
```

and the dynamic pages:

```
<footer class="subnav clearfix dinMenu">
  <a class="button next right" href="#" data-href="child.html" data-module="1">Next</a>
</footer>
<!-- end panel specific content -->
<script>
 din();
</script>
```

If I remove the script from the "child.html" file, nothing happens when I press next.

Comment: "And .on isn't working" well, that's your problem. You're not doing it right. You need to use `on` to solve this problem; "rerunning" your JavaScript  isn't really possible or practical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('.dinMenu').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
```

which puts the event handlers on all the `<li>` elements, put the handler on the `<body>`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.dinMenu a', function(event) {
```

That way the event handler will remain in effect even when the menu is reloaded. There's no need to set it up again after an ajax reload, in other words.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you don't need to recall the function.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!! As soon as the option is available, I'll set it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put the entire function on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dinMenu').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#dinContent').html('loading...');
        var $this = $(this);
        var module = $this.data("module");
        var folder = 'modules/module_' + module + '/';
        var href = $this.data("href");
        var url = folder + href;
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#dinContent').html(data);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#dinContent').html("Error!! File is not loaded");
        });
    });
})
```

So you don't have to call it into the `<script>` tag in the footer

Hope this helps

Comment: That was how it was before and decided to place it before. But the problem was that I was targeting the <li> only. Changing the target to Body solved it. Thank you anyway.